# Woocommerce error after loading variation items with ajax in archive page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

im using the archive pages of the shop to navigate for every product using ajax, after i load the product and show it i reload the add-to-cart-variation.min.js and it seems to work but when i choose a variation i get an error in console.

My script is:

js

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: ajax_var.url,
                    data: "action=" + ajax_var.action + "&nonce=" + ajax_var.nonce + "&id=" + id,
                    success: function(result){

                        jQuery('#mk-archive-products').append('<div id="resultado-ajax">'+result+'</div>');
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        loadVariationScript();
                    },
                });

function loadVariationScript() {
jQuery.getScript("/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min.js");    
    jQuery('.variations_form').each(function () {
            jQuery(this).wc_variation_form();
        });
}
```

php:

```
function my_event_list_cb() {
    $nonce = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['nonce'] );
    $product_id = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['id'] );

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'my-ajax-nonce' ) ) {
        die ( 'Busted!');
    }

    

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post__in'=> array($product_id)
    );


    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
        }
    }

    wp_die();
}
```

The error i get in console when i chose a variation is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.getElementById(...) is null
    jQuery 22
        m
        onFoundVariation
        dispatch
        handle
        trigger
        trigger
        trigger
        each
        each
        trigger
        onFindVariation
        dispatch
        handle
        trigger
        trigger
        trigger
        each
        each
        trigger
        onChange
        dispatch
        handle
jquery.js line 2 > eval:1:13099
    jQuery 22
        m
        onFoundVariation
        dispatch
        handle
        trigger
        trigger
        trigger
        each
        each
        trigger
        onFindVariation
        dispatch
        handle
        trigger
        trigger
        trigger
        each
        each
        trigger
        onChange
        dispatch
        handle
    receiveMessage resource://gre/actors/SelectChild.jsm:268
    receiveMessage resource://gre/actors/SelectChild.jsm:465
```

Anybody knows a way to get the products in this archive page and make that the variation form works?
Thx in advance